# Construct a username based on name given and +1 counter (if username already exists)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to construct a username based on name given. Since many people are named "John" I need to somehow check for this and create it by following a +1 count.

I'm a bit lost in how to iterate ActiveRecord to find in this case a username called `john`, then if already exists try `john1` and if not available try `john2` and so on. I can suppose it would use `while` but I have no idea how to iterate it for this case.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to not make multiple trips to the database, get a list of users that match the name, check the count of users, append the count to the name, and then check the already loaded collection for the new name.

It would look something like this:

```
name = params[:name]
users = User.where(User.arel_table[:name].matches("#{params[:name]}%")).to_a
count = users.length

name_without_collision = if count > 0
  loop do
    break "#{name}#{count}" unless users.any? { |u| u.name == "#{name}#{count}" }
    count += 1
  end
else
  name
end
```

Since you're calling `to_a` on the `ActiveRecord::Relation`, you don't have to worry about accidentally sending multiple queries to the database, since it is being converted to a standard Ruby array.

Comment: Mmm. for some reason 2nd line query returns only one object "John" even if there's already a "john1" in the database.

Comment: You're going to have to add a percent sign to do a wildcard.  For example: `name = "#{params[:name]}%"`.

Comment: This returns an object like `"John%3"`. If I run a `name.gsub('%','')` I get a `"John"`. The result should be in this case `John3` instead.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, sorry about that.  Look at my edit.  Just move the place where the `%` is appended to `name` to the query itself.

Comment: This code has a catch: If `John` is not taken it will return `John0`. It should return `John` instead.

Comment: Good call... Updated my answer.