# Add number to regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

We have a Facebook app with a Google login/register. Some of the accounts do not provide a username, so the application must create one before saving the object in the database.

We currently solve the problem this way:

```
user.username = "#{user.email[/^[^@]*/]}_#{user.id.to_s}"
```

The problem is, we use `mongodb/mongoid` like `database/odm` and generate a username that is too long, like:

```
hyperrjas_50ad43d11d41c86b27000066
```

In this case we added the `user.id` after `hyperrjas`.

We want to add a unique number instead of the unique `id` if the username is already taken, something like:

```
hyperrjas
hyperrjas1
hyperrjas2
hyperrjas3
...
```

How can we do it?

Comment: you will have to know how many users with the given name are present in your database and I don't think this can happen without performing a query to the database.

Comment: Thank you, can you add a example with optimized query to database for check if username is already taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a question similar to this earlier.  This is what I came up with:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13794784/367611

**Update per comment**

You can make a method out of this by doing:

```
def prevent_collision(user)
  name = "#{user.email[/^[^@]*/]}"
  users = User.where(:username => /^#{name}/).to_a #Return an array and after use length method with users.length. Without .to_a is not working because is returned a mongoid criteria.
  count = users.length

  if count > 0
    count = rand(1000)
    loop do
      break "#{name}#{count}" unless users.any? { |u| u.name == "#{name}#{count}" }
      count += rand(10)
    end
  else
    name
  end
end
```

Where the returned value will be either the originally generated name or the name with a count appended to it.  Then you could do, for example:

```
@user.username = prevent_collision(@user)
@user.save
```

Comment: Thank you I use mongoid 2.4.12. Is it valid for mongoid 2.4.12?

Comment: Excellent.  I knew that's how I used it, but I've been working with older versions of Mongoid.  Good to know that it still works that way.

Comment: Thank you but I'm sorry but I have checked with accounts hyperrjas@gmail.com and hyperrjas@hotmail.com and I get the error `Validation failed - Username is already taken`. Where is the error?

Comment: Are you using `name_without_collision`?

Comment: This is the problem, i have added this code to one method. Is possible add this code to one method for to be used more than once? Thank you

Comment: Sure, take a look at my update.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Ah, yeah... That was a typo.  You may actually want to do `/^#{name}/`, since you want to return users who have `hyperrjas1`, `hyperrjas2`... `hyperrjasN`.

Comment: There's a small chance of a race condition here where two records might think the same one is available and jump on it. You might want to either pick random 3 or 4 digit numbers to avoid that, or have some kind of retry logic to rescue from the inevitable exception. This could happen if two simultaneous calls to the create user procedure kick off.

Comment: @tadman can you write the code to fix the problem you raise in your last comment please? Thank you very much!

Comment: @hyperrjas: The chance of a race condition actually happening is super small.  In any case, you can use the above edit instead.

Comment: I just mean that you should attempt to save and rescue on `validates :uniqueness` errors by looping again.

Comment: The error was fixed. I have replaced: `users = User.where(:username => /^name/ ).to_a` by `users = User.where(:username => /^#{name}/).to_a` and now is working fine :D. Thank you very much!. Regards!

Comment: I had `.to_a` there at the beginning.  I'm glad it's working now.

Comment: Now it's working fine with the same username with all email accounts. I have checked with the same alias with gmx.com, gmail.com, hotmail.com, yahoo.com...etc and the code generate a unique username for each email account. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a useful idea:

```
username = "hyperrjas001"
try_name = username.dup
10.times do
  raise "username maximum reached: #{username}." if try_name.end_with('999')
  try_name = try_name.next
  puts try_name
end

# Output:
#hyperrjas002
#hyperrjas003
#hyperrjas004
#hyperrjas005
#hyperrjas006
#hyperrjas007
#hyperrjas008
#hyperrjas009
#hyperrjas010
#hyperrjas011
```

Comment: Thank you Can you write the example with query inside database to check if username is already taken? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be suitable for incrementing:

```
username.sub(/^(.*\D)(\d*)$/) { "%s%d" % [ $1, $2.to_i + 1 ] }
```

As an example:

```
username = 'hyperrjas'
username2 = username.sub(/^(.*\D)(\d*)$/) { "%s%d" % [ $1, $2.to_i + 1 ] }
# => "hyperrjas1"
username3 = username2.sub(/^(.*\D)(\d*)$/) { "%s%d" % [ $1, $2.to_i + 1 ] }
# => "hyperrjas2"
```

This can be repeated as required until you get a unique name. Note that it will mangle names like `lucky99` to `lucky100`, though, not `lucky991`.

Comment: Thank you but I need to know how it works the query to database!

Comment: How are you accessing your database now?

Comment: Thank you @tadman for your help. The SeanHill answer is correct.